# Serve huge file via php, not located in public_html

Tags: php

I want to serve huge files from a folder above the `public_html`.

Currently I do:

```
<?php

    // Authenticate
    if ($_GET['key'] !== "MY-API-KEY") {
      header('HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden');
      echo "You are not authorized.";
      return;
    }

    define('CHUNK_SIZE', 1024*1024);
    $PATH_ROOT_AUTOPILOT_ACTIVITY_STREAMS = "../../../data/csv/";

    // Read a file and display its content chunk by chunk
    function readfile_chunked($filename, $retbytes = TRUE) {
        $buffer = '';
        $cnt    = 0;
        $handle = fopen($filename, 'rb');

        if ($handle === false) {
            return false;
        }

        while (!feof($handle)) {
            $buffer = fread($handle, CHUNK_SIZE);
            echo $buffer;
            ob_flush();
            flush();

            if ($retbytes) {
                $cnt += strlen($buffer);
            }
        }

        $status = fclose($handle);

        if ($retbytes && $status) {
            return $cnt; // return num. bytes delivered like readfile() does.
        }

        return $status;
    }

    // Get the file parameter
    $file = basename(urldecode($_GET['file']));
    $fileDir = $PATH_ROOT_AUTOPILOT_ACTIVITY_STREAMS;
    $filePath = $fileDir . $file;

    if (file_exists($filePath))
    {
      // Get the file's mime type to send the correct content type header
      $finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
      $mime_type = finfo_file($finfo, $filePath);

      // Send the headers
      header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$file.csv;");
      header("Content-Type: $mime_type");
      header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($filePath));

      // Stream the file
      readfile_chunked($filePath);
      exit;
    }
?>
```

This currently fails for some reason I don't understand. `curl` outputs:

```
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  457M    0  457M    0     0  1228k      0 --:--:--  0:06:21 --:--:-- 1762k
curl: (92) HTTP/2 stream 1 was not closed cleanly: INTERNAL_ERROR (err 2)
```

Is there a better way to serve big files programatically, via PHP?

Currently about 2/3 of the file is served. The response is not complete because it crashes. There are no logs.

Comment: you could do it in chunks, download the file by 3rds and append to a file?

Comment: @treyBake seems very user-unfriendly

Comment: OP, seems like a CSV. Any chance you can compress it?

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca it does, but I've never had an API that downloads a huge file from elsewhere before .. this is a.. "*good*"-ish guess

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca Well... Probably yes, but that would mean to manually zip it every time. And later if the zip file is big enough, it will probably fail the same way it fails now.

Comment: out of interest, how big we talking here?

Comment: @treyBake Currently it's a 2GB csv file.

Comment: Probably unrelated, but that `ob_flush` is useless without a corresponding `ob_start`.

Comment: Use symlink to public_html. For Authenticate use mod_rewrite %{QUERY_STRING}

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca I took that function from another SO answer and they probably took it from the PHP forums, and `ob_start` doesn't appear anywhere... ‍♂️ Could that be the problem maybe...?

Comment: At this point I would try to stick `ob_start()` before the loop and try, but I'm just guessing.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca I tried that, but it does not work...

Comment: Yes got same issue. No idea other than increasing PHP memory and script time.